# Force www subdomain in lighttpd and preserve path

Tags: redirect, lighttpd, 301-redirect

I would like to setup my lighttpd powered website to redirect users to the www subdomain when browsing the site without the subdomain. I would also like it to preserve the trailing URL and serve the redirect as a permanent 301 redirect. What sort of rules would I need to throw into my `lighttpd.conf` file?

```
example.com -> www.example.com
example.com/pagename -> www.example.com/pagename
```

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect all requests on example.com to www.example.com while preserving the original path:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^example\.com$" {
  url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "http://www.example.com/$1" )
}
```